# Why does "Any bounded sequence $(x_n)⊂H$ contains a sub-sequence $(x_{n_k} )$ such that $(Cx_{n_k} )$ converges."?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators, locally-compact-groups

I was reading "Hilbert Space Operators
in Quantum Physics" by Jiˇrí Blank • Pavel Exner • Miloslav Havlícek ˇ

> A linear everywhere defined operator $C$ on $H$ is said to be compact
> if it maps any bounded subset of $H$ to a precompact set. Since $H$ is a metric space, this is equivalent to the
> requirement that any bounded sequence $(x_n)⊂H$ contains a
> sub-sequence $(x_{n_k} )$ such that $(Cx_{n_k} )$ converges.

I am not able to deduce the following statement.

> any bounded sequence $(x_n)⊂H$ contains a
> sub-sequence $(x_{n_k} )$ such that $(Cx_{n_k} )$ converges.

**My attempt:-**

$(Cx_{n_k} )$ is a sequence in locally compact space. ($\because$ C is a compact operator.)
I am not able to proceed further. Could you help me?
I also know that
A set $M$ in a complete metric space $X$ is precompact iff
it is completely bounded. In particular, if X is a finite–dimensional normed
space, then $M$ is precompact iff it is bounded.

Comment: Do you know that a metric space is compact iff every sequence has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: Also, which direction of the equivalence are you asking about? Both?

Comment: @EricWofsey yes sir.

Comment: But locally compact space need not be compact. I know that compact space is locally compact.

Comment: "Precompact" does not mean "locally compact".  It means its closure is compact.

Comment: @EricWofsey Sorry, I got that from googling. Thank you for correcting me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by Eric Wofsey is correct: If $C$ is compact, then $C(A)$ being precompact means that $\overline{C(A)}$ is compact.

Let $C: H \to H$ be a linear operator on $H$, and suppose $C$ is a compact operator. Now, let $A = \{x_n\} \subset H$ be a bounded sequence. Since $A$ is bounded, the image sequence $C(A) = \{Cx_n\}$ is precompact. Hence, $\overline{C(A)}$ is compact. At this point, if you know compactness in a metric space is equivalent to every sequence having a convergent subsequence, we are done because $\{Cx_n\}$ is a sequence in the compact space $\overline{C(A)}$.